# Почему устанавливается nodejs старой версии на digitalocean?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, digitalocean

При установке node.js на digitalocean, устанавливается версия 12.22, и при обновлении пишет, что это самая новейшая?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

потому что в дистрибутиве она фиксируется на дату выпуска дистрибутива.

Для получения более новых версий воспользуйтесь способами 2 или 3 по инструкции
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-22-04

или отсюда

https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions